# Why is there no color in the scene I exported with vtkVRMLExporter

Tags: vtk

I want to export the result, but there is always no correct color after opening it with ParaView.
If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

```
    polydata = vtkAppendPolyData()
    reader = vtkNIFTIImageReader()
    reader.SetFileName('Brats18_2013_10_1_seg.nii.gz')

    for label,color,name in zip(labels,Colors,CC):
        pointColors = vtkUnsignedCharArray()
        pointColors.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
        pointColors.SetName('Colors')

        dmc = vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes()
        dmc.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        dmc.SetValue(0, label)

        smooth = smooth_functions(dmc, 1)

        output = smooth.GetOutput()

        for i in range(output.GetNumberOfPoints()):
            pointColors.InsertNextTuple3(*color)

        output.GetPointData().Update()
        output.GetPointData().SetScalars(pointColors)
        polydata.AddInputData(output)


    mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(polydata.GetOutputPort())
    actor = vtkActor()

    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    ren = vtkRenderer()
    ren.AddActor(actor)
    renWin = vtkRenderWindow()
    renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
    iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()

    exporter = vtkVRMLExporter()
    exporter.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
    exporter.SetActiveRenderer(ren)

    exporter.SetFileName("test.wrl")
    exporter.Write()
```

I originally used multiple actors to display different parts, but the exported result cannot be opened by ParaView, so I used vtkAppendPolyData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the difference between two (VTK ?) concepts: `Exporter` and `Writer` (and their counterpart `Importer` and `Reader`)

### Exporter/Importer

An exporter is intended to store the whole scene, in term of visible objects, in a file. It takes into account each object, the background, current colors etc ...
Importing the resulting file should provide a same-looking scene.
But in the process you can lose a lot of info, not visible at the export time

### Writer/Reader

They are intended to write only one but full dataset on the disk, and is unrelated to any kind of visualization properties. It contains usually a mesh and associated data but no background color or such things.

### Your problem

You are mixing both approach. ParaView use the `Reader` paradigm but you use the `exporter` one. That is probably why you cannot open the file with the multiple actors version, and why you do not have color now.

### Possible solutions

1. First way is to make sure the colors you want are correctly rendered. If yes, maybe the export / reader will work.
2. Another possibility is to use a writer instead of the exporter. There is no `vtkVRMLWriter` (from my quick search at least) but you can use any format supporting polygonal meshes (as the [vtkXMLPolyDataWriter](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/IO/WriteVTP/) )
3. The last option, the cleaner from my point of view, is to keep separate objects: you can get rid of the `vtkPolyDataAppend` and replace it with [vtkGroupDataSetsFilter](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGroupDataSetsFilter.html#details) and write it (for instance) with `vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter`)

Comment: Thank you, the third method solved my problem :)